# Android Galaxy Tab : Why is the launch icon surrounded by a pink border?

Tags: android, tabs, icons

I followed the icon design guidelines from android and so I have icon in different size:

```
drawable-hdpi (96x96)
drawable-hdpi (72x72)
drawable-ldpi (36x36)
drawable-mdpi (48x48)
```

But on the Samsung Galaxy Tab the icon gets a weird purple/pink-ish border. The Game 'Angry Birds' seems to have the same problem. Facebook was able to change it to blue. So what is this border and how can I remove it?

Screenshot

[image: Applications]

Answer (score 4):

I've observed that the Tab picks some background color to use to frame your icon, even if the icon is rendered with a transparent background: the calendar has a dark frame, gmail has the same pinkish/purple color as Angry Birds, and my icons which have transparent backgrounds/no borders on the Nexus 1 have weird blue colors. In fact, ALL of the icons on the Tab have a background and border. I've had to conclude there is no way to get rid of it, and there is currently no published algorithm as to how it picks the color.

Comment: That's really unfortunate to hear. It does explain why facebook and googles border are blue. I have an custom application called PAC-MAC Championship and that has no border. I tried to put a 114x114 icon in there to see if perhaps the DPI had something to do with it but it just resizes to 72x72 and still has the border.

Answer (score 0):

This answer from
user
@int ermedi_8

to question
[Can Icon Border Be Eliminated In Android App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461570/can-icon-border-be-eliminated-in-android-app)

seems to work on my Samsung device: I don't know whether it works on other brands. Of course it only helps for your own apps where you can put code into AndroidManifest.xml.

Quote:-

Though it is old, maybe it still helps someone:

Thanks to @deloreyk hint about TouchWiz i found this site where Josh Barton suggests to add a meta tag to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.samsung.android.icon_container.has_icon_container"
android:value="true"/>
```