# Can Icon Border Be Eliminated In Android App?

Tags: android

I put an application icon of size 72x72 for HDPI. Still icon border is there, can it be shown without border? Any help please. I am using Sumsung Galaxy S.

Comment: what is 'boader', do you mean 'border'?

Comment: Sorry for mistake in Spelling. It is border, Can it be removed ? Please help...Thanks for ur valuable time to help me out!

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of how it looks with the border?  I use standard PNG with transparency for my app icons - and the border is not being shown anywhere.

Comment: like this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117072/android-galaxy-tab-why-is-the-launch-icon-surrounded-by-a-pink-border]

Comment: I too used transparent PNG but it shows background Alexs. How can I overcome this problem? Thanks for ur valuable time to help me out!

Answer (score 3):

Though it is old, maybe it still helps someone:

Thanks to @deloreyk hint about TouchWiz i found [this](https://medium.com/@AthorNZ/disabling-touchwiz-icon-frames-c7cb4b626180) site where Josh Barton suggests to  add a meta tag to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.samsung.android.icon_container.has_icon_container"
android:value="true"/>
```

This solved it for me!

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the rounded square behind your icon, that is part of the `Samsung TouchWiz UI` they put on most of their phones. I don't know of a way to remove it, because I have never had a TouchWiz device; but I assume it can't be removed. You could try downloading a different launcher from the market, such as LauncherPro.

Comment: But some of the app icons are with out border in Sumsung Kevin. So I want to apply icon with out border. It is strange that some icons are without border and some of icons with . How it could possible?

Comment: Apologize, I did some poking around but I couldn't find anything on the TouchWiz for Android. I found a tool for customizing "widgets" for Bada, but I don't think it will help you. Also stumbled on a site that said that it adds the border to every icon.